# Want to send a copy of outgoing mail to my manager gmail account automatically

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I have tried this using google script but it doesn't work.
I want to make any application or through API which will help me with this function. Whenever i am sending any mail a copy of that should automatically go t my manager's gmail account. How should i do this in c#
 application or with google script?

Answer (score 1):

your question is very general theirs not much we can do for you.

but here's your options.

If you really want to program something you can use c# with google's [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) or [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview) and forward sent mail through that.

But that is so unneeded for what you are trying to do. I recommend looking into Gmail rules/filters. you create a rule where any specified action within gmail happens triggers another action

Check out this article [Fwd. copy of sent mail to other email automatically](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUTwAb-XPoNlc)

you can't directly put a rule on sent mail but you can put a rule on your outbound mailbox where certain mail gets forwarded to someone else.

Or you know use, the BCC function that emails have. [How to Use the CC and BCC Features in Gmail](https://www.gmass.co/blog/how-to-cc-in-gmail/). It's honestly all your looking for, the other stuffs extra.